# How much time it takes to install IIS on EC2 Windows

Tags: iis-7, installation, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008

I've initialized an IIS7 installation on Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 server. Right now it is still in the "Initializing Installation" process, and I am already 15 minutes during the installation. Is there something wrong, or it takes so much time to install IIS on Windows 2008?

Comment: This question is not for stackoverflow. And also it's impossible to answer without knowing the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the only one with this problem
http://www.cloudcomputingetc.com/2011/10/iis7-takes-too-much-time-to-install-on.html